# Trigonometric functions are not working in LPC Xpresso IDE

Tags: c, embedded, arm

I am using LPCXpresso IDE for programming LPC1769, as core library CMSISv2p00_LPC17xx is being used. And I Have chosen REDLIB None by default.

problem that I am encountering, is that, Trigonometric functions are not working, I have included math.h too, its not showing any errors or warning, using of functions like sin, cos, tan and etc returns zero value always.

Any suggestion and help regards to this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: The math library is usually separated from the C library (activated by giving `-lm` to the linker. In embedded environments you may not even have the math library. Try looking in the documentation for your compiler.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Math Library is available with REDLIB.Long back i used it. trig functions worked perfectly fine

Comment: 1) post example 2) How do you know the return value is 0 and not 1e-30?  Suggest `%e` as in `printf("%e %e\n", 0.841, sin(1));`